# Fill DropDownList with options using comma-separated text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I have text like

> important,offtopic,business

I want to use this string to fill a dropdown list.
Data is comma-separated text, not JSON.

```
<select name="ctl00$Content$ucShare$ddlTag" id="ctl00_Content_ucShare_ddlTag">
<option value="important">important</option>
<option value="offtopic">offtopic</option>
<option value="business">business</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your text in array format.Then using each loop in jquery you can fill up dropdown list.

```
var array = $('#yourfield').val().split(",");

var dllist= $('#yourdropdownid');

$.each(array,function(i){
    dllist.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(array[i]).html(array[i])
    );
});
```

working demo here
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharadpanwal/hyb1vyue/1/)